# Angular 2 => no provider for {ClassName}

Tags: angular

I try to send the selected item value "c[3]" using angular 2.
What I want is : When I select an item, the details about that item are displayed. Then I click in submit to send this value and wait for a reply. My problem is in the second part, I can not send the selected item through the form. An error is displayed when I try the code I have written:

> inline template:14:8 caused by: No provider for standard!

---

selectedinput.html

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" >
   <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "selection2" (change)="selectionChanged()"  name="addresseAdmin" >
       <option *ngFor="let c of users" [ngValue]="'E-mail : '+c[2] +'&nbsp;'+'@: '+ c[4]" > {{c[0]}}&nbsp;{{c[1]}}</option>
      </select>
       <br> {{selection2}}

      </div> 
     </div>
</form>
```

---

selectedinput.component.ts

```
 constructor(public adminService :adminService,private standard: 
 standard) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.adminService.getData().subscribe(response=>{
     this.users=response.users,console.log(this.users)
   });
 }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {  
     this.standard.create(this.addresseAdmin)
          .subscribe(response=>{console.log("response",response);

        })
    }
```

---

sendreponse.service.ts

```
  @Injectable()
  export class standard {
    handleError: any;
    private Url ='http://localhost:3000/register/permission';
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
    private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      return body || { };
    }
    create(addresseAdmin): Observable<any> {
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.post(this.Url, addresseAdmin, options)
                .map(this.extractData);
      }


    }
```

I want to send only the c[2] value in the form knowing that my data are stocked in an array!

Comment: I updated the title to reflect the answer. I hope it will help other people later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your standard class into the providers of your module :

```
import {standard} from 'somewhere/over/the/rainbow'

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        standard
    ]
})
```